# How to bind complex objects to Telerik's RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, asp.net-ajax

I have to create a table to monitor a list of streams.
The table, as you can see from the attached, must have the following features:

- The stream description (or name) to be monitored
- The type (input, output or both)
- The results of a particular day (**and here is the problem**)

This is the desidered result:
[image]

The data streams are provided by Web Service, via JSON.

I planned on doing everything with the RadGrid, but I have some difficulties in its implementation.

This is the **model** to pass:

```
[DataContractFormat]
public class StreamOutputDto : BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<DetailStream> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Where "**DetailStream**" is:

```
public class DetailStream
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int CountInfo { get; set; }
    public StateStream StateInput { get; set; }
    public StateStream StateOutput { get; set; }
    //...
}

public enum StateStream
{
    InProgress,
    Received,
    Declined,
    Inexistent
}
```

So *DetailStream* is the result of a specific stream in a specific day.
*Details* is a list of DetailStream, ie the results of a specific stream in a specific week.

With Name and Type there are no problems, but I do not know how to manage the list of DetailStream. Someone can help me?

This is my current implementation:

My **Web Service**:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    StandardResponse<StreamOutputDto> GetStream(string request);
}


[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[MessageLoggingBehavior]
public class MyService : IMyService
{

    public StandardResponse<StreamOutputDto> GetStream(string request)
    {
        // TEST CASE:
        StandardResponse<StreamOutputDto> response = new StandardResponse<StreamOutputDto>();
        response.Output = new StreamOutputDto();
        response.Output.Name = "Hi!";
        response.Output.Type = "Input";
        response.Output.Details = new List<DetailStream>();

        response.Output.Details.Add(new DetailStream(){
                Id = "1",
                CountInfo = 100,
                Date = DateTime.Today });

            response.Output.Details.Add(new DetailStream(){
                Id = "2",
                CountInfo = 200 });

        return response;
    }

}
```

My **WebForm.aspx**:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="RadGridParser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
    <telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true"/>

    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" RenderMode="Lightweight" ClientDataSourceID="RadClientDataSource1" 
             AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="false" PageSize="5" runat="server">

        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Name" ClientDataKeyNames="Name">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="" DataType="System.String" >
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Type" HeaderText="Tipologia flusso" DataType="System.String">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Day1" HeaderText="Lunedì">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Day2" HeaderText="Martedì">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Day3" HeaderText="Mercoledì">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Day4" HeaderText="Giovedì">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Day5" HeaderText="Venerdì">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>

    </telerik:RadGrid>

    <telerik:RadClientDataSource ID="RadClientDataSource1" runat="server" AllowBatchOperations="true">
        <ClientEvents OnCustomParameter="ParameterMap" OnDataParse="Parse" />
        <DataSource>
            <WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
                <Select Url="http://soldev/Axa.Sol.Web/ws/Ivass/IvassService.svc/GetStream" DataType="JSON" RequestType="Post" />
            </WebServiceDataSourceSettings>
        </DataSource>
        <Schema ResponseType="JSON">
            <Model ID="StreamModel">
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Name" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Type" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Day1" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Day2" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Day3" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Day4" DataType="String" />
                <telerik:ClientDataSourceModelField FieldName="Day5" DataType="String" />
            </Model>
        </Schema>
    </telerik:RadClientDataSource>

</body>
```

My **RadGridParser.js**:

```
//<![CDATA[
function ParameterMap(sender, args) {
    //If you want to send a parameter to the select call you can modify the if 
    //statement to check whether the request type is 'read':
    //if (args.get_type() == "read" && args.get_data()) {
    if (args.get_type() != "read" && args.get_data()) {
        args.set_parameterFormat({ request: kendo.stringify(args.get_data().models) });
    }
}

function Parse(sender, args) {
    var response = args.get_response();
    if (response) {
        args.set_parsedData(response.Output);
    }
}

function UserAction(sender, args) {
    if (sender.get_batchEditingManager().hasChanges(sender.get_masterTableView()) &&
                !confirm("Any changes will be cleared. Are you sure you want to perform this action?")) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    }
}

//]]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadGrid can't handle this out of the box. The only thing you can do I think is to use a TemplateColumn. The template column has a "ItemTemplate", "InsertTemplate", and an "EditTemplate".

You can put any controls and html elements inside this container. Also you can access this controls (and your data item) inside the "ItemDataBound" event of the grid. This should help you to achive your scenario.

References:
[Template Columns](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/appearance-and-styling/customizing-with-gridtemplatecolumn)

Item-DataBound Event:

```
protected void RadGrid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
 {
  GridDataItem gridItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
  dynamic dataItem = (YourType)(gridItem.DataItem);
  gridItem.ToolTip = dataItem.ID + " - " + dataItem.UUID;
 }
}
```